# Looping through directories in Python using f-string

Tags: python, containers, azure-data-lake-gen2, f-string

I am trying to access 2 different directories in ADLS using for loop & f-string but facing issues in doing so

```
# Primary storage info
 account_name = "accountnamehere"  # fill in your primary account name
 container_name = "logscontainer"  # fill in your container name
 subscription_id = "subscriptionname"
 resource_group = "My-Resource-ML" # fill in your resource gropup for ADLS account
 workspace_name = "My-Workspace-ML" # fill in your la workspace name

 datasets=[test1,test2]
 for df in datasets :
    input_path = f"datasets"
    print(input_path)
```

I get the following error

```
----> 8 datasets=[{test1},{test2}]
      9 for df in datasets :
     10     input_path = f"datasets"
```

NameError: name 'test1' is not defined

Can someone help ?

Comment: First of all, code in error is different than the one you provided. 2nd, the error is pretty clear. You are trying to use variable which is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
datasets = ['test1', 'test2']
for df in datasets:
    input_path = f"{df}/subdirectory"
```

?